# Split a string with special character in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I have a string with multiple special character, I want it to be split it with the special characters.

Example:

```
s = "apple+onion*abc/ki&jk"
```

Output:

```
apple
onion
abc
ki
jk
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way of doing, this is just slightly changing the regular expression

```
strPhrase = "apple+onion*abc/ki&jk"

Set objRegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.RegExp")
objRegEx.IgnoreCase = True
objRegEx.Global = True
objRegEx.Pattern = "[^a-z0-9]"
ReplacedText = objRegEx.Replace(strPhrase, " ")

objArr = Split(ReplacedText)
For i = 0 To UBound(objArr)
  If Trim(objArr(i)) <> "" Then
    Debug.Print objArr(i)
  End If
Next

Set objRegEx = Nothing
```

Comment: Be careful if words you want to keep together have spaces in them. Choose a character to split on that will not be in the data.  Of course the split character should be blocked at the point of data entry for this to work 100%. We all know how that goes :-/

Comment: I have tried with different combination with the code, it works exactly what I want.

Answer (score 3):

You can make it like this way :

```
Dim s : s = "apple+onion*abc/ki&jk"
Dim r : Set r = New RegExp
r.Global = True
r.Pattern = "\+|\*|&|®|@|/"
NewString = r.Replace(s,"_")
wscript.echo NewString 
Tab = Split(NewString,"_")
For i=LBound(Tab) to Ubound(Tab)
    Msg = Msg & Tab(i) & vbCrlf
Next
wscript.echo Msg
```

Answer (score 1):

This also one of the method to split the string..

```
Dim s:s="apple+onion*abc/ki&jk"

ReDim words(-1)


  For Each line In Split(s,"+")
   For Each linetwo In Split(line,"*")
    For Each linethree In Split(linetwo,"/")

     For Each linefour In Split(linethree,"&")

         ReDim Preserve words(UBound(words)+1)
         words(UBound(words))=linefour

     Next

    Next
   Next
  Next


for i=0 to 4 step 1
    Msgbox(words(i))
Next
```